# Как подключить MediaPlayer к слайдеру изображений?

Tags: android, mediaplayer

Есть слайдер изображений, записанных на карту памяти. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сюда прикрутить MediaPlayer для воспроизведения своего mp3 на каждой странице? То есть нужна реализация озвученных слайдов (картинок).
Вот код activity:

```
public class SliderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static final String TAG = "myLogs";
    ViewPager viewPager;
    CustomSwipeAdapter adapter;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_slider);
/*
 * Читаем json и создаем из него объект книги bookFiles
 */
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        int bookId = GetBookId();
        String fileName = "book_" + bookId + ".json";
        String gsResult = MyJSON.getData(getApplicationContext(), fileName);
        BookFiles bookFiles = gson.fromJson(gsResult, BookFiles.class);
        /*
        Получаем из объекта bookFiles массивы путей к файлам книги
         */
        ArrayList<String> pagesFiles = bookFiles.getPagesPath();
        ArrayList<String> soundsFiles = bookFiles.getSoundsPath();

        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        adapter = new CustomSwipeAdapter(this, pagesFiles, soundsFiles);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        //слушаем номер слайда при перелистывании
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                int page_number = position+1;
                Log.d(TAG, "onPageSelected, position = " + page_number);
//                Uri soundUri = Uri.parse(soundsFiles.get(position));
//                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(soundUri);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
    }

    public int GetBookId(){
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int bookId = intent.getIntExtra("bookId", 1);
//        Log.d(TAG, "You read book №" + bookId);
        return bookId;
    }
}
```

Comment: так у вас всё правильно. в onPageSelected прерываете предыдущее проигрываиние и вызываете play() для нового

Answer (score 0):

Решил таким образом. Код ниже. Как и подсказывал Sviat Volkov, я прервал предыдущее проигрывание в onPageSelected

```
public class SliderActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    static final String TAG = "myLogs";
    ViewPager viewPager;
    CustomSwipeAdapter adapter;
    ToggleButton toggleButton;
    ImageButton imageButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_slider);
        imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonHome);
        View.OnClickListener clickHome = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mp !=null && mp.isPlaying()){
                    mp.stop();
                }
                GoHome();
            }
        };

        imageButton.setOnClickListener(clickHome);
/*
 * Читаем json и создаем из него объект книги bookFiles
 */
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        int bookId = GetBookId();
        String fileName = "book_" + bookId + ".json";
        String gsResult = MyJSON.getData(getApplicationContext(), fileName);
        BookFiles bookFiles = gson.fromJson(gsResult, BookFiles.class);

        final String folderB = "bookfiles_" + bookId;
        /*
        Получаем из объекта bookFiles массивы путей к файлам книги
         */
        ArrayList<String> pagesFiles = bookFiles.getPagesPath();
        final ArrayList<String> soundsFiles = bookFiles.getSoundsPath();

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());
        adapter = new CustomSwipeAdapter(this, pagesFiles);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonPlay);

        //слушаем номер слайда при перелистывании
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                String nameS = Uri.parse(soundsFiles.get(position)).getLastPathSegment();
                if(mp != null){
                    mp.stop();
                }
                getMedia(nameS, folderB);
                toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(SliderActivity.this);

                if (toggleButton.isChecked()){
                    mp.start();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

    }

    public int GetBookId() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int bookId = intent.getIntExtra("bookId", 1);
        return bookId;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) mp.start();
        else if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.pause();
        }

    }

    public void getMedia(String nameS, String folderB) {
        final String soundPath = String.valueOf(getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(folderB));
        final Uri souF = Uri.fromFile(new File(soundPath, nameS));
        final MediaPlayer mp = MyPlayer.getMp(getApplicationContext(), souF);
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    }

    private void GoHome() {

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SliderActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }, 10);
    }

}
```